# iAD View Freezes On Ad Close

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, iad

Ok, so after testing on the simulators it turns out that this issue is **only occurring on actual devices**... How would I fix this?

---

I am making an iOS app with SpriteKit and am implementing iAD. Everything works more or less like I expect it too, except for one thing. When I tap on the ad, it brings me to a full screen ad, as expected, but when I close that ad the current view freezes, as in nothing happens visually. I know  the app is still running because when I click the banner ad again and close out of it again the game returns to normal and the game had progressed while visually frozen. This is how the banner is initialized in my view controller class (the iAD delegate):

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

CGRect bannerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 20, scene.size.width, 50);

banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
banner.delegate = self;
banner.frame = bannerFrame;
[banner setAlpha:0];
[self.view addSubview:banner];
```

And these are the loading methods, also in the view controller class:

```
- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *) bannerM
{
    NSLog(@"Ad Loaded");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [bannerM setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)bannerM didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Ad Failed");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [bannerM setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I don't really understand the problem or why it is happening... Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

StrongJoshua

*EDIT* Here are the two methods that are called when the banner ads open and close:

```
- (BOOL) bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    if(playing)
    {
        NSLog(@"Ad Pause");
        SKView *v = (SKView *)self.view;
        NSLog(@"2");
        SKScene *s = (SKScene *)v.scene;
        NSLog(@"3");
        WBPlayScene *p = (WBPlayScene *) s;
        NSLog(@"4");
        [p.logic pause:YES];
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void) bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if(playing)
    {
        NSLog(@"Ad Unpause");
        [((WBPlayScene *)((SKView *)self.view).scene).logic pause:NO];
    }
}
```

**FIXED**
The reason for all those NSLogs is because the game crashes when I try to pause it. The game crashes after "2" is reached, so at `SKScene *s = (SKScene *)v.scene;`. It gives the error `[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` and I don't understand why...
**Solution:** To fix this side issue I changed `self.view` to `self.originalContentView` and it got the SKView instead of the ad banner's view.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: did you implement the `protocol`'s methods `bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:`
 and `bannerViewActionDidFinish:`?

Comment: @lootsch yes, and I'm trying to use them pause the game when the user is actually ingame. Idk if I implemented them correctly, so I'll add them to the question (along with a probably minor issue I'm having with them).

Comment: I think the problem is, that `self.view` isn't a `SKView` (as expected) but a `UIView`. Try to check this. This should work in order to pause your game.

Comment: We've had this repeatedly in recent weeks: the iAD view has replaced your SKView's viewController.view with the iAd banner view. I don't know why this happens but it seems a recurring issue that something wrong about the iAd setup.

Comment: @lootsch Ok, so that's that issue mostly explained, but what is the reason for the first question (the one that I created this post for originally), about the screen not refreshing?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I found that using self.originalContentView gets you the SKView, thanks! But I still have the issue with the non-refreshing screen after closing out of the ad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** I had to remove the call to enable ad display `self.canDisplayBannerAds` because it interfered with my self-created banner.